# How can i create Emgu.Cv.Image<,> from pointer

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I simply want to convert an Emgu.Cv.Image<,> from a pointer, I am using the following code:

```
Size img = CvInvoke.cvGetSize(frame);
Image<Bgr, Byte> tImg = new Image<Bgr, byte>(img.Width, img.Height, 0, frame);
```

I don't know what value to give in 3rd parameter of Image<,> constructor that takes a pointer. It says **Size of aligned image row in bytes** what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Note that image width has to be a multiple of 4 since some OpenCV code optimization is based on this assumption when CVImage is constructed from a memory 1D array.